# Send request body to serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

in my Django project, I have the following for serializers and views

serializers:

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Animal
        fields = [
            'pk',
            'name',
            'animal_type',
            'weight',
            'color',
        ]
```

views:

```
class AnimalRudView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView): 
    serializer = AnimalSerializer

    def create(self,request):
        body = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8')
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM animals WHERE " + body['search'])
            animal = [dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

In views, I get a request body with certain conditions ( as " search ": " weight>20 "), which gives me then all objects which match these conditions. 
I want to add this body to the serializer as well because I want to fill the fields list automatically. 
Do you have any idea how I can parse the body into the serializer?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

As an example from one of my custom `post` methods from a class extending `CreateAPIView`:

```py
class BaseQuestionCheckerView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        # I can now access the validated data from my
        # serialiser. But first I have to call is_valid():
        try:
           serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except Http404:
           raise Http404

        validated_data = serializer.validated_data

        # common thing to do with serializer.validated_data
        # is to return it.

        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Hope that gets you on the right track!